# Display alternate content after webform submission

Tags: webforms

Is there a way to display an alternate content once user submits a webform?

For example user submits "Email Sign Up" form on the homepage, and the next time they visit the page containing that form they would see a different message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that for anonymous visitors, webform does store a cookie so that it knows if you've submitted a particular form (assuming a default webform configuration). So in theory, you could hook into that with some custom code to display and/or hide content.